# 複合条件での検索結果が出てこない状態になってます。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

今、ruby on railsで複合条件の検索を実装をしています。二つのカラムの項目があって、そのカラムに一致するレコードを表示されるようにしようとしています。viewとmodelを変えたのですが、まだ二つが重なる条件が出てきません。どうぞ教えていただけたら、嬉しいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```js
Controller 

def index
  @plans = Plan.includes(:guider).page(params[:page]).per(5).order("created_at DESC")
  @plans = Plan.page(params[:page]).per(5).order("created_at DESC").search(params[:search])
end
```

```css
Model

def self.search(search) 
      if search 
        Plan.where("(datetimes like ?) AND (title like ?)", "%#{params[:search1]}%", "%#{params[:search2]}%")
      else
        Plan.all
      end
end
```

```html
<div class="david">
   <%= form_tag plans_path, :method => 'get', :class => 'david' do %>
    <p><strong>Place: </strong></p>
    <div style="width: 250px;" placeholder="date" >
      <p><%= text_field_tag :datetimes, params[:search1] %></p>
      <p><%= text_field_tag :title, params[:search2] %></p>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> def self.search(search) 
>       if search 
>         Plan.where("(datetimes like ?) AND (title like ?)", "%#{params[:search1]}%", "%#{params[:search2]}%")
> ```

モデルの中では`params`は参照できません。素直に書き換えるのであれば

```
def self.search(search1, search2) 
  if search1 && search2 
    Plan.where("(datetimes like ?) AND (title like ?)", "%#{search1}%", "%#{search2}%")
```

として、呼び出す側も引数を2つ渡すように書き換えてください。

Answer (score 0):

## clientからserverへ値の渡し方

@suzukis さんの回答の通りmodelでは`params`をそのまま用いることはできません。

また、viewで

`<%= text_field_tag :datetimes, params[:search1] %>`

とすると、`params[:search1]`が`nil`であった場合生成されるhtmlは

`<input type="text" name="datetimes" id="datetimes">`

となります。

`params[:search1]`や`params[:search2]`のように`:datetimes`ではないkeyを用いて`params`を呼び出しているので、clientから送られてきたパラメータを適切に扱えてないように思えます。

## controllerで`@plans`の複数定義

```ruby
def index
  @plans = Plan.includes(:guider).page(params[:page]).per(5).order("created_at DESC")
  @plans = Plan.page(params[:page]).per(5).order("created_at DESC").search(params[:search])
end
```

とありますが、２回目の`@plans = ...`で１回目の`@plans`を上書きしているので、冗長化と思われます。

## その他

どのようなスキーマなのかわからないので、ただしいクエリが発行されいているかどうかは現状なんとも言えません。

それを確認するにはリクエスト・レスポンス時の`rails server`でどのようなSQLが発行されているのかを見ることと、controllerでの`@plans`をdumpして適切なデータを取得できているかを見ることをお勧めします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。どうしたら、clientから送られてきたパラメーターを適切に受け取ることができますか？よろしくお願いします。